# Check in changeset is merged programmatically

Tags: c#, tfs, tfvc

I'm retrieving tfvc changesets related to a WorkItem. My next step is that i want to check if they are merged to a specific branch. I don't find anything about how to do this in c#.

Today what i have is this:

```
using (var changeSetClient =
                new TfvcHttpClient(_uri, _credentials))
            {

                foreach (var relation in wi.Relations.Where(r => r.Url.Contains("Changeset")))
                {
                    var changeset = changeSetClient.GetChangesetAsync("Welfare_Research_2009", relation.Attributes["id"]).Result;
                    changeset.

                }
            }
            return null;
}
```

I can also get the right TfvcBranch that i wanna know if it's merged to.

But how can i check if it's Merged? Much like how the "Track Changesets" functionality in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, [**VersionControlServer.TrackMerges()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ff732621(v=vs.110)) is the API you want to use.

```
TrackMerges(array<Int32[], ItemIdentifier, array<ItemIdentifier[], ItemSpec)
```

**Gets merges that occurred from a source item to a set of target items, for a list of source Changeset IDs.**

> In the sourceItem parameter, pass the root of the branch you want to
>   track changes from.  In the targetItems parameter, pass the root of
>   the branches that you want to track the changeset to.  Note, this will
>   only work for branch roots that have a merge relationship.  The best
>   way to make sure that is true is to view the branch hierarchy and make
>   the branches are directly related or related through some route.
>
> Let's say you wanted to track a changeset from $/Proj/Main to
>   $/Proj/Feature2 in a branch hierarchy like this:
>
> ```
> $/Proj/Main
>     $/Proj/Dev
>        $/Proj/Feature2
> ```
>
> Then you would want to pass $/Proj/Main in as your sourceItem and
>   $/Proj/Dev AND $/Proj/Feature2 as targetItems.

More detail code and sample please refer this blog: [TFS API - TRACK CHANGESET MERGE IN BRANCHES](https://benclarkrobinson.net/tfs/2014/07/07/tfs-api-track-changeset-merge-in-branches/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The blogpost in the end is dead though.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient ways to do that, but you could query the history for the respective branch using something like this:

```
// pseudo code
var parameter = new QueryHistoryParameters();
parameter.RecursionType = RecursionType.Full;
parameter.IncludeChanges = true;
// set other members to potentially filter out unneeded stuff
// especially, say, "VersionStart" / "VersionEnd".

var result = workspace.VersionControlServer.QueryHistory(parameter);

foreach (var entry in result)
{
     // Compare "entry.ChangesetId" with the ID of the changeset you're looking for.
}
```

Note that the reference to the VersionControlServer interface can be gathered by different means. Above I assumed you already have workspace reference.